# array data is not visible to li tag when pushed in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm new to angularjs. I'm trying to create a to do list app. The problem i'm facing is when i push the data to the object, the data is being displayed in the console but not the web page. I"m using materialize css framework as well. Here is my html code.

```
        <head>
            <title>Shamanager</title>
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/materialize/bin/materialize.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">
        </head>

        <body>
            <div class="container" ng-controller="tasks">
                <h3 class="center-align"><i>Hola! Sham</i></h3>

                <form class="row" ng-submit="enter()" novalidate>
                    <div class="col s12">
                        <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
                            <li>
                                <div class="collapsible-header" ng-repeat="thing in lists">
                                    <i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i> 

                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <div class="collapsible-header">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter task" class="input-field center-align" ng-model="name" type="submit">
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div ng-submit="">
            <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/app.js"></script>
            <script src="bower_components/materialize/bin/materialize.js"></script>
        </body>

        </html>
```

And here is my javascript code.

angular.module('manager', [])

```
        .controller('tasks', function($scope) {

            $scope.lists = [
            ]

            $scope.name = '';


            $scope.enter = function() {
                console.log('hello world');
                $scope.lists.push($scope.name);
                console.log($scope.name);
                $scope.name = '';
            }

        })
```

Comment: Well, for one, your `<input>` has two `type` attributes.

Comment: it doesn't work eventhough i use only one

Comment: Angular always needs an action to be happend so it knows that something was changed and everything needs to be recalculated. So you have to call `$scope.$apply()` in your enter-method after you pushed an item to the array.

Comment: @Teemoh That shouldn't be the case since `enter` is called by `ngSubmit` which would trigger a digest anyway.

Comment: You code works. Just use `{{ thing }}` somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it seems to me that you have a lot of unclear knowledge about HTML in the first place and of Angular in the second place.

Some errors I spotted:
You have a form with

1. Your input field on the form has multiple type attributes but it would only need `type="text"`
2. You are using ng-submit on strange places ( but it would be enough on the form)
3. There is no way for displaying the data in the ng-repeat over lists. You need to display the items with ´{{ thing }}`, for example:

```html
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="listItem in lists">{{ listItem }}</li>
</ul>
```

Overall I would really recommend you to study some examples like this ones to become more familiar with the way angular should work:

- https://codepen.io/Russbrown/pen/IgBuh
- https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_todo_app
- https://scotch.io/tutorials/creating-a-single-page-todo-app-with-node-and-angular

Here is also a quite good tutorial on what you want to achieve:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1STpbC44bRA

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer helped me a lot